# use autocomplete in v-for

Tags: autocomplete, vuejs2, v-for

im very new on vuejs2 but im trying using it!.

Im using a v-autocomplete component, I downloaded from here:

https://github.com/paliari/v-autocomplete

The component is inside a loop v-for, i can't set the props correctly all props is reflected on all components, what's the correct way?

here an image to understand:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNleQ.png

My code:

```
<template v-for="lote in remate.lotes">
   <v-autocomplete
       :items="items"
       :ref="'search'"
       :v-model="loteClienteForm.cliente"
       :get-label="getLabel"
       :keep-open="true"
       input-class="form-control"
       :component-item='UserAutocompleteTemplate'
       @update-items="updatedItems">
   </v-autocomplete>
</template>
```

My vue page:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Autocomplete from 'v-autocomplete'
import UserAutocompleteTemplate from '../components/template/UserAutocompleteTemplate'

export default {
    middleware: 'auth',
    scrollToTop: false,
    components: {
        'v-autocomplete': Autocomplete
    },
    data: () => ({
        items: [],
        item: {},
        loteClienteForm: new Form({}),
        UserAutocompleteTemplate: UserAutocompleteTemplate
    }),
    methods: {
        getLabel (item) {
            if(item !== null){
                return item.nombre
            }
        },
        updatedItems (text) {
            this.searchRemateClientes(text).then( (response) => {
                this.items = response;
            })
        },
        async searchRemateClientes(search){
            const { data } = await axios.get('/api/search/remate-clientes', {params: {query: search}});
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `v-model` in your example is `loteClienteForm.cliente` which is not dependent on the `v-for` for `lote`, hence all the `v-autocomplete` components are using the same value as their model.

Note that you are also missing the [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) attribute property in your `v-autocomplete` components.

Comment: thanks you, I fixed it putting the loteClienteForm in a component! it work awesome now!